# How can a FILE* (pointer to a struct) be tested (if == NULL)?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I was playing around with C, anyways I was thinking how can file pointer (which points to a struct type), be tested if NULL as for instant:

```
FILE *cfPtr;
if ( ( cfPtr = fopen( "file.dat", "w" ) ) == NULL )
```

I tried to do that myself, but an error occurs.

```
struct foo{
    int x;
};

struct foo bar = {0};

if (bar == NULL)
    puts("Yay\n");
else
    puts("Nay");
```

---

> error C2088: '==' : illegal for struct

Here's the FILE deceleration in the stdio.h file:

```
struct _iobuf {
        char *_ptr;
        int   _cnt;
        char *_base;
        int   _flag;
        int   _file;
        int   _charbuf;
        int   _bufsiz;
        char *_tmpfname;
        };
typedef struct _iobuf FILE;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It should be a *pointer to* a struct:

```
struct foo* bar = ...

if (bar == NULL)
    puts("Yay\n");
else
    puts("Nay");
```

Pointers to structs can indeed be tested for nullness, just as pointers to primitive types.

Answer (score 4):

You must take care of the distinction between a value and a pointer. Pointers hold the address of a value - usually (although not always) a value allocated using malloc().

In your example

```
struct foo bar = {0};

if (bar == NULL)
    puts("Yay\n");
else
    puts("Nay");
```

bar is allocated on the stack - it is **not** a pointer, so you cannot compare it with NULL (which is a value - in fact 0 on every implementation I have used).

You probably want something more like

```
struct foo* bar = malloc(sizeof(struct foo));

if (bar == NULL)
    puts("Yay\n");
else
    puts("Nay");

bar->x = 0;
```

Notice that you cannot put a value into bar until you have checked whether it is not NULL. If you forget this you will get a NULL pointer dereference error.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to point to something that contains a null. That's not the same as a pointer with the value 0, which points to the address null of its address space.

The manpage says: "Upon  successful  completion  fopen(),  fdopen()  and  freopen()  return  a FILE pointer.  Otherwise, NULL is returned and the global variable errno is set to indicate the error."

In the case that it returns 0 there is no valid FILE struct to point to.

Answer (score 2):

`FILE *p` is a pointer and it is meaningful to compare it with NULL value. On the other hand,

```
struct foo bar = {0};

if (bar == NULL)
```

makes no sense (not the one you want at least), nor it does a thing like `&bar == NULL`; the latter would work, but would be always false, since `struct foo bar = {0}` 's memory exists for sure. So indeed there's no way how there can be a failure for `struct foo bar;`: the memory is "allocated" correctly or the program fails some other way.

```
struct foo *bar;
bar = malloc(sizeof(struct foo));
if ( bar == NULL ) // ...
```

says that bar is a pointer (and we try to malloc the needed memory to hold struct foo), and so `bar == NULL` is ok.

You can say somethig like `FILE p` which is different from `FILE *p` (and not suggested, `FILE *` must be considered an "opaque" pointer you shouldn't be interested to, since it may be different in different implementation)

**Add after reading a comment of the asker**

```
FILE *cfPtr;
if ( ( cfPtr = fopen( "file.dat", "w" ) ) == NULL )
```

This works since first the left inner () is evaluated, and so the cfPtr is assigned to the result of fopen, like if it were an alone statemente `cfPtr = fopen(...)`. After that, this same result (the value of cfPtr) is compared to NULL. `fopen` returns a `FILE *` of course, and a pointer can be compared to NULL.

Answer (score 0):

if your Q is how can this code work:

```
if ( ( cfPtr = fopen( "file.dat", "w" ) ) == NULL ) ?
```

==> its equivalent to

1. `cfPtr = fopen( "file.dat", "w" )` //Note that, fopen returns `FILE*` that gets
                                      //assigned to cfPtr
2. `if( cfPtr == NULL)`

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can test some of its members? Maybe _ptr or _tmpfname, for instance?

Comment: I that, my question is how can this code work:

    if ( ( cfPtr = fopen( "file.dat", "w" ) ) == NULL )

?

Comment: I just tried if((cfPtr = fopen("file.dat","w")) == NULL) return 1;    and it compiled OK.

Comment: @m4design: Your question is clear, however in your examples `cfPtr` is a pointer while `bar` *is not* ;  it is an instance of a struct, not a pointer to a struct.  Use "struct foo* bar = 0` instead.

Comment: @Vnunce:  I think you have misunderstood m4design's question.  He simply wants to know why his code does not work when the FILE* example does.  The answer is simply that he is not using a pointer at all in his example.

Comment: @Clifford: Yup... I totally missed the idea of the question. I need coffee :)